# Can I purchase/activate SIM card around Poznan Glowny station after 20:00?

Tags: cellphones, poland, poznan

I'm going to move to Poznan from Berlin using DB train. However, the arrival time is 19:27, and I must purchase and activate SIM card immediately in order to get to my AirBnB room.

According to [Prepaid data SIM card wiki on Poland](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Poland), I can purchase a SIM card anywhere but the registration must be done from July 2016, which must be in "the stores and sales outlets of the providers".

> It's not possible anymore to buy a prepaid starter set without showing your ID. Take care, that some places like kiosks still sell them, but you can't register there. But without registration, you SIM card won't be activated. That's why it's recommended to go directly to an operator's store instead located in towns and shopping centers.

But I wonder if these shops are still open around 20:00. Is it possible to buy a SIM card and activate it after I arrive at Poznan Glowny station at 19:27? Or is there any other way to get a mobile network?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the same complex as Poznań Główny station there is a shopping center [Avenida Poznań](http://avenidapoznan.com/) open until 9 PM (Monday-Saturday) and until 8 PM on Sundays. There are three mobile providers where you can buy and register a prepaid card, [T-Mobile](http://avenidapoznan.com/sklepy/t-mobile/#sklep022) and [Plus](http://avenidapoznan.com/sklepy/plus/#sklep024) and [Play](http://avenidapoznan.com/sklepy/play/#sklep021).

So on Sundays it may be risky, other days you will be fine for sure.

Comment: Thanks and good to hear that! Are you sure these stores also operate until 21:00? It is on weekdays for your information.

Comment: @Blaszard T-Mobile for sure, you can confirm on this site http://www.t-mobile.pl/pl/dlaciebie/obsluga-klienta/kontakt/formularze/lead-4 (choose Poznań / Ul. Stanisława Matyi 2). Other two for 99% too, that's how it works in all Polish cities :)

Comment: Thanks. I booked the ticket and am looking forward to visiting Poland!

Answer (score 2):

With the answer by @Kuba I purchased a SIM card there.

Orange didn't sell SIM cards, so I purchased it at T-Mobile.

However, **the registration process takes up to 30 minutes**. This is because you must buy your SIM card first, and after the verification is completed you must top it up. The verification process takes about 20 minutes, so the whole process takes near 30 minutes. You must make a payment twice (the first is 5 PLN to buy the card, and then 20 PLN to top it up).

So **I would encourage the future visitors to arrive at least before 20:30** to make sure that you can purchase and activate it successfully.